# How can I rewrite my function to only accept array? Help me to find error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make my notification function receive an array, but when I try to send my data, it fails with this error message:

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4168' AND type = 'low stock'' at line 1 SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN '4168' AND type = 'low stock' Filename: models/Notification.php

---

My new function (rewritten to accept array):

```
  public function addNotification($data){
            $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
            if (isset($types[$data['type']]) === false) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
            }
            $type = $types[$data['type']];
            $timestamp = time();
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
            $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($data['product_id'],$data['type']))->result_array();
            if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                try {
                    foreach ($data['product_id'] as $pid) {
                        if (!$this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $pid, $data['user_id'], $timestamp))) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
```

My old function (with use of separated parameters):

```
public function addNotification($message, $product_id, $user_id, $type = ''){
        $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
        if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
        }
        $type = $types[$type];
        $timestamp = time();
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
        $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($product_id, $type))->result_array();
        if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try {
                foreach ($product_id as $pid) {
                    if (!$this->db->query($sql, array($message, $type, $pid, $user_id, $timestamp))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this tests let me to add more than once

```
public function addNotification(Array $data) {
        /*$types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
        if (isset($types[$data['type']]) === false) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
        }
        $type = $types[$data['type']];
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id = ? AND type = ? ";
        $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($data['product_id'],$data['type']))->result_array();
        if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            try {*/
                //foreach ($data as $pid) {
                    //if( !$this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $data['product_id'], $data['user_id'], $data['timestamp'])) ) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $data['product_id'], $data['user_id'], $data['timestamp']));
                        //return false;
                  //  }
                //}

                //return true;
            //} catch (Exception $e) {

            //}
        //} else {
          //  return true;
        //}
    }
```

So, my new function `$data` parameter looks like this:

```
  $entryData = array(
           'message' => 'low stock',
           'product_id' =>  $value['id'],
           'user_id'  => $this->session->log['id'],
           'type'     => 'low stock'
    );
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
$this->notification->addNotification($entryData);
```

Can anybody tell me where is the error?
Thanks!

[image: table_statucture]

Comment: public function addNotification(Array $data){ //code }

Answer (score 0):

`right syntax to use near ''4168'`
Looks like your `user_id` SQL WHERE part is generated with additional apostrophe, but it is not expected to be there.
Code looks fine, can you try this code queue?
Firstly, replace your new function with this:

```
public function addNotification(Array $data) {
    $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
    if (isset($types[$data['type']]) === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
    }
    $type = $types[$data['type']];
    $timestamp = time();
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
    $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($data['product_id'],$data['type']))->result_array();
    if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            foreach ($data['product_id'] as $pid) {
                if( !$this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $pid, $data['user_id'], $timestamp)) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, try executing this:

```
$entryData = array(
    'message'    => 'low stock',
    'product_id' => array($value['id']),
    'user_id'    => $this->session->log['id'],
    'type'       => 'low stock'
);

$this->notification->addNotification($entryData);
```

And see if it will work.

Comment: it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach() because of the foreach

Comment: That's because your $entryData['product_id'] is not array, but you treating it as an array in your function. See edited answer.

Comment: yea, how can I foreach only the ids

Answer (score 0):

This is written in codeigniter right? Make use of Active Record

```
public function addNotification($data)
{
    $types = array(
        'new'       => 0, 
        'pending'   => 1, 
        'low stock' => 2
    );

    if (isset($types[$data['type']]) === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
    }

    $type = $types[$data['type']];
    $timestamp = time();

    $select = array(
        "COUNT(*) AS notificationCount"
    );
    $where = array(
        "type" => $data['type'])
    );
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->where_in('product_id', $data['product_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get('storelte_notifications');
    $previousNotification = $query->row();

    if ($previousNotification->notificationCount > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($data['product_id']) {
            foreach ($data['product_id'] as $pid) {
                $insert_fields = array(
                    "message"   => $data['message'],
                    "type"      => $data['type'],
                    "product_id"=> $pid,
                    "user_id"   => $data['user_id'],
                    "timestamp" => time()
                );
                $this->db->insert('storelte_notifications', $insert_fields);
            }
            return true;               
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: why when I try to add a new one with the same dont add it?

Comment: @FernandoOsuna what do you mean the same? same what?

Comment: example if I want to insert the notification for the same product dont it..

Comment: well you can provided you have set your table structure correctly. could you post your table structure?

Comment: if I insert my data like this I can insert as many as i want ...   $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $data['product_id'], $data['user_id'], $data['timestamp']));

Comment: did you set the primary key of table storelte_notifications to autoincrement?

Comment: yes of course, if I do something like this I can ...  $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $this->db->query($sql, array($data['message'], $data['type'], $data['product_id'], $data['user_id'], $data['timestamp']));

Comment: maybe because the `'product_id' =>  $value['id']` you passed from `$entryData` contain only one value, can you confirm to pass an array of product ids instead

Comment: it can be , how can I add them twice the same id?

Answer (score 0):

use bracket in your in clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN (?) AND type = ? ";
```